# Android SDK, Placeing widgets/buttons etc at will?

Tags: android

Hey Im new to android developing and I have a quick question. Is there a way to place buttons where I want them on the view? Right now they only seem to be placed where there is specific spots for them. Why cant i drag and place them where ever I want like in the iphone sdk for example?

Is there a way to do so or does this functionality not exist? thanks.

Comment: It exists, you just really don't want to use it since it will make your life very difficult trying to support multiple screen sizes, resolutions, densities, aspect ratios, and orientations. As all of the answers below point out, Android provides automated layouts that will preserve your design while smoothly scaling to any screen Android supports. You can also write your own layouts if you need something custom.

Answer (score 2):

Android (eg. similar to Qt) uses a concept of [layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html). This is especially useful when you're creating UIs that can be displayed on different devices with different DPIs, different screen resolutions, etc.

So instead placing your buttons at pixel coordinates you put them, independent of device screen resolution, into layouts.

Read more in [User Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html) documentation. Using Eclipse ADT plugin you can visually create layouts. You can even embed one layout into other, creating eg. LinearLayout in RelativeLayout. This gives much more possibilities of creating screen scalable applications (one app on phone and tablet for example).

Answer (score 1):

There is [AbsoluteLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html), but that class is deprecated. The recommended strategy is to use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) (you can control the position of views by setting layout margins) or build your own custom layout class.

Answer (score 1):

An android UI screen is build for various screen sizes , due to which you can not specify an exact location for the UI component .

Android instead uses the concepts of Layouts where each layout has a different behavior. Here are a few of them.

- LinearLayout aligns all children in a single direction — vertically or horizontally, depending on how you define the orientation attribute
- TableLayout positions its children into rows and columns
- RelativeLayout , one of the most used layouts , lets child views specify their position relative to the parent view or to each other (specified by ID).

Answer (score 0):

A UI element's position is determined by the layout you choose. See [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html#Layout).

Answer (score 0):

Android uses layouts to design the UI. For example, a vertical linear layout stacks one element on top of the other.
AbsoluteLayout is the most precise, but it's also harder to maintain and can get messy.
I recommend RelativeLayout. It positions UI elements relative to other elements.

If you don't really need that much precision, one more option is nesting layouts within layouts. But doing that too much gets messy and RelativeLayout becomes the better option.